# Migrating to razor, A hard one

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, migration

I am wondering how can I convert this helper to razor

```
<% Html.AjaxForm(s =>
 { %>
<div class="form2">
    <br />
    <label class="smallLabel" for="Name" >
        Name : <span id="s_Name">*</span></label>
    <%=Html.TextBox("Name", ViewData.Model.Name, new { @class = "smallTextBox" })%>

</div>
<% });%>
```

Comment: try Razor converter from http://www.telerik.com/community/download-free-products.aspx, Maybe not worked everytime but help in most case.

Answer (score 2):

```
@using(Ajax.BeginForm(new AjaxOptions()))
{
    <div class="form2">
        <br />
        <label class="smallLabel" for="Name" >Name : <span id="s_Name">*</span></label>
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name, new { @class = "smallTextBox" })
    </div>
}
```

I strongly recommend you revisit [razor syntax info](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/01/06/razor-syntax-quick-reference.aspx)

**UPDATE**

The following syntax:

```
@using(Html.BeginForm())
{
}
```

will render the following html:

```
<form>
</form>
```

Whatever you put inside the curvy brackets will be inside the `<form>` tags.

Comment: just try it... @using in razor html helper syntax gets a bit different meaning. I updated answer, but seriously, check out razor syntax info

Comment: Sorry, I am not using mvc form helper. AjaxForm is our helper and take Action<string> as parameter. I have to use AjaxForm.

Comment: I don't know how exactly your custom helper works. Try slapping @ in front of it and getting rid of all `<%` `%>` stuff. What's is the reason you can't use method provided by MVC framework?

Comment: Thanks everybody, We switched back to aspx render engine. it seems razor dose not have abilities to render such things